# How do I access/change the material on an imported gltf-object in three.js individually?

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I exported an object from Blender to a gltf-file and imported it into my three.js project. (Including materials, ive got 2 in total)

```
let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

loader.load('Objects/MyBox.gltf', (gltf) => {

let box = gltf.scene;

box.traverse((child) => {
                        if (child.isMesh) child.material = boxMaterial; // a material i created in the code earlier
                    });
                    scene.add(box);
                });
```

This code causes my imported Object (which is a folded box) to have the same material (boxMaterial) on the outside and on the inside.
But as i created it in bleder ( inside of the box has an inside material, the outside has an outside material) i want it to be in my three.js project. What I want is = the boxMaterial(created in three.js) shall only be on the outside-Material(created in blender).

My question is -> how do I tell/access the specific imported material of my imported object to have a certain material in three.js?

**In easier words:** My "child.material" contains my needed materials from blender.(2 in total) But how do I access only the first one?

I think I'm looking for something like box.children[0].material.. or so. The index 0 is my outside material.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Regarding your question, if you can share what you did and the exact error you received, we may be able to help you see what went wrong.

Comment: My issue already got solved. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: If you fixed your own issue, please consider posting how you fixed it as an answer to your own question.